# How to redirect to multiple servers sitting behind HAProxy which have different path begining

Tags: routes, load-balancing, haproxy

I have 3 servers which listen on following port ,

```
> 10.21.5.39:80    -->   api.something.com
> 10.21.4.234:80    -->   *.something.com
> 10.21.5.73:80     -->   coolapi.something.com
> 10.21.5.73:3002    -->   school.something.com
```

I am using a HAProxy server to redirect the traffic to these backends, i am using the following config on haproxy which doesn't seem to workout.

```
frontend api
       bind *:80
       acl url_api path_beg /api
       use_backend api-backend if url_api

frontend custui
       bind *:80
       acl url_custui path_beg *
       use_backend custui-backend if url_custui


frontend backoffice
       bind *:80
       acl url_backoffice path_beg /backoffice
       use_backend backoff-backend if url_backoffice

frontend partnerui
       bind *:80
       acl url_partnerui path_beg /partner
       use_backend partner-backend if url_partnerui


backend api-backend
    mode    http
    option  httpchk
    server  api01 10.21.5.39:80

backend custui-backend
    mode    http
    option  httpchk
    server  custui01 10.21.4.234:80

backend backoff-backend
    mode http
    option httpchk
    server backoff01 10.21.5.73:80


backend partner-backend
    mode http
    option httpchk
    server backoff01 10.21.5.73:3002
```

So the idea is to let HAProxy listen on 80 and then redirect to the backends listening on the specified port.. Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- You have multiple `frontends` all listening on port 80; I would recommend having a single frontend and using ACLs to direct traffic to your `backends`. From [the HAProxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-use_backend):

  > There may be as many "use_backend" rules as desired. All of these rules are
  >   evaluated in their declaration order, and the first one which matches will
  >   assign the backend.
- You provide `option httpchk`, but do not have any support for checks on your `server` lines; from the HAProxy documentation (1.5.18 specifically, but comparable for other versions)

  > The port and interval are specified in the server configuration.

  I would recommend adding an interval (in ms), such as

  ```
  server  custui01 10.21.4.234:80 check inter 2000
  ```
- You are specifying `mode http` and `option httpchk` in each backend; these can be combined in the `defaults` section and then overridden in a backend if necessary.
- I like using `hdr(host)` to check for the HTTP request's URL, so I would rewrite `acl url_api path_beg /api` as `acl url_api hdr(host)     -m beg api.`, but that is down to personal preference

Combining those recommendations with your listed requirements, here is an updated version of your configuration file:

```
defaults
   mode    http
   option  httpchk

frontend something.com
   bind *:80

   acl url_api path_beg /api
   use_backend api-backend if url_api

   acl url_backoffice path_beg /backoffice
   use_backend backoff-backend if url_backoffice

   acl url_partnerui path_beg /partner
   use_backend partner-backend if url_partnerui

   # Catches anything not covered by use_backend above
   default_backend custui-backend

backend api-backend
    server  api01    10.21.5.39:80   check inter 2000

backend backoff-backend
    server backoff01 10.21.5.73:80   check inter 2000

backend partner-backend
    server backoff01 10.21.5.73:3002 check inter 2000

backend custui-backend
    server  custui01 10.21.4.234:80  check inter 2000
```

Comment: do you have an example of haproxy with multiple frontends but each front end has different port or is listening to its own port?

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul You could use the example code I posted, but duplicate the `frontend` stanza and change the listening port in the `bind` line.

This could be done if you wanted a different frontend to listen for (e.g.) HTTPS traffic (use port 443).